# Group data by range, not all numeric data in R

Tags: r, range

I have a data set with a column that has numbers that represent medical codes.

Group 1

1. 100
2. 200
3. 400
4. 510
5. 430
6. 330
7. V220
8. E560

I would like to put those in groups that represent the category they fall in. For example 100-200 would be in the "Infectious" column, 400-550 would be in the "Neoplasm" column etc.
How do I deal with codes that begin with letters?

Comment: How do you want to deal with them? Does V220 fall in the 201-300 range, or is there a "V" range, or something else?

Comment: All the ones that start with letters are not in the same categories as the numbers. They fall into their own category

Comment: So anything with a letter is its own category, or each letter defines a category? Like, if there is V220 and V880, do they get lumped into a V category, or are they separate categories? Or all the ones with letters go into a single letters category?

Comment: All the ones with letters to begin with are in the same category, it would be a category labeled "Other". It doesn't matter what letter it begins with.

Comment: The example is just a few entries, there is 65,000 entries and the numbers range from 001 to 999, and then some with letters to begin with.

Comment: Do you expect different columns or just one column with different labels?

Comment: One column with different labels

Answer (score 1):

We can use `cut` and then `coalecse` with the original data

```
library(dplyr)
newgrp <- with(df1, as.character(cut(as.numeric(Group1), breaks = c(-Inf, 100, 200, 300, 400, 550, Inf),
       labels = c("categ1", "Infectious", "categ2", "categ3", "Neoplasm"))))

coalesce(newgrp, df1$Group1)
```

Comment: So between the 300 to 400 break, I just wanted 325 to400, not 300 to 400.

Comment: @CrnDg I guess you wanted either a `filter` after converting to `numeric` or change the `labels`.  Not clear to me.

Comment: @CrnDg what happens to those values between 300 and 325.  Are those removed or change to NA

Comment: They would need to go into the "Other" category

Comment: @CrnDg Then, change the `breaks` and `labels`, accordingly ie. `breaks = c(-Inf, 100, 200, 300, 325, 400, 550, Inf), labels = c('categ1', 'Infectioous', 'categ2', 'Other', 'categ3', ..`

Comment: When I do this it works, but when I change it to a factor so I can use it for classification modeling, each entry is its own factor. I would like there to be only 8 factors, "categ1", "Infectious", etc..

Comment: @CrnDg wrap with `yourdata <- droplevels(yourdata)`

Comment: Error message no applicable method for 'drop levels' applied to an object class "list"

Comment: @CrnDg I assumed your data is either a `data.frame` or `vector` then it should work.

Comment: I tried a data frame and vector and get the same error message.

Comment: @CrnDg ok.  No reproducible example from your part.  Here is one with a reproducible one. `data(iris);levels(iris$Species) <- c(levels(iris$Species), "A", "B");levels(iris$Species)#
[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"  "A"          "B"`. Now use `droplevels` `iris <- droplevels(iris);   levels(iris$Species)#
[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"`